# Would would happen, if I created a svc with an identical name?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have an svc running eg `my-svc-1`,
and I run a deployment that makes an svc of the same name `my-svc-1`. What would happen?

Comment: it seems like it was blocking it

Answer (score 2):

Service should be unique within a namespace but not across a namespaces. The uniqueness applies to all namespace-based scoping objects for example Deployment, service, secrets etc.

> Namespaces provides a mechanism for isolating groups of resources within a single cluster. Names of resources need to be unique within a namespace, but not across namespaces.

If you really need the same service with the different software version, you can create another `namespace` named `B` and then you can create a service having name `my-svc-1`.

[working-with-objects-namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Comment: Ok yep I understand that, my question I was just wondering what would actually happen. And I tried it, and it seems like the previous svc with the same name just blocks the new one from being deployed

Comment: If there is uniqueness then it mean no new entry can override the existing one, same like this primary key in database, Kubernetes also using distributed database etcd